# Problem when trying to access data from vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex4

I tried to put my water data in `Vuex` and everything went ok until I try to access my data array.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        categories: {}
    },
    getters: {
        categories: (state) => {
            console.log(state.categories);
            return state.categories;
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        set_categories: (state, data) => {
            state.categories = data
        }
    },
    actions: {
        get_categories: (context) => {
            axios.get(`${baseUrl}/api/categories?pagination=0`)
                .then((response) => {
                    context.commit('set_categories', response.data);
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Here is all the code in vista and that's how I access it in the vista component

```
mounted() {

        this.$store.dispatch('get_categories'); 
    },
```

```
computed: {
        stateCategories() { 
            return this.$store.state.categories 
        }
    },
```

```
console.log(this.stateCategories)
```

But my data does not appear.
Do you know what the problem is?
I tested with vue tools developers and my data appears in `vuex`

Answer (score 1):

Try to wait for response :

```
async mounted() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('get_categories'); 
},
```

Comment: Same thing. I got only this dep: Dep
id: 9
subs: []
[[Prototype]]: Object
value:
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
[[Prototype]]: Object
vmCount: 0
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: @KoulJak hey mate, and what do you get in console.log(state.categories)?